# Angular- How to skip valuechanges for one of the form elements

Tags: angular

I have 3 form elements defined this way:

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
  name: ['', Validators.required],
  email: ['', Validators.required],
  preference: ['', Validators.required]
});

this.form.valueChanges
  .pipe(
    filter(
      ({ name, email}) => name.length > 0 || email.length > 0
    ),
    takeUntil(this.destroyed$)
  )
  .subscribe(value => {
    this.onChange(value);
    this.onTouched();
  });
```

How do I make sure `valueChanges` is not triggered when the value of `preference` is changed?

Answer (score 2):

I think an approach would be to override the built-in `updateValueAndValidity` method such that it has `{ onlySelf: true }` added by default.

```js
this.form = this.fb.group({
  foo: ['', Validators.required],
  bar: ['', Validators.required]
});

const fooControl = this.form.get('foo');
fooControl.updateValueAndValidity = fooControl.updateValueAndValidity.bind(
  fooControl,
  { onlySelf: true }
);
```

[Working demo.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvvzmr?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

This works because `updateValueAndValidity` is responsible for [*bubbling* the `valueChanges`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L748) event from a child form control(in this case, `foo`) to a parent form control(in this case, the `form` `FormGroup`):

```js
if (this._parent && !opts.onlySelf) {
  this._parent.updateValueAndValidity(opts);
}
```

So, what this approach does it to make sure that whenever this control gets its `updateValueAndValidity` method invoked, it will always have the `onlySelf` option set to `true`.

The `updateValueAndValidity` can be invoked by either manually by using `formControl.setValue()` or automatically by a `ControlValueAccesor`.

---

If you'd like to learn more about the `@angular/forms` package and its inner workings, you could check out [A thorough exploration of Angular Forms](https://indepth.dev/posts/1143/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms).

Answer (score 0):

Jake, you can change a little your valueChanges, put pairwise before the filter and try it:

```js
 this.objFormGroup.valueChanges
      .pipe(
        pairwise(),
        filter(
          ([prev, next]) => prev.name != next.name || prev.email != next.email
        )
      )
      .subscribe(form => {
        console.log(form);
      });
```

If you want to see how I do it completely, you can see in the StackBlitz through this link: [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jgw8sv?file=src/app/opponent-details.component.ts)

Pairwise bring to us the previous and the next value, so now we can see if what field changed

Besides, you can prevent the change event be trigger by valueChanges with it, if you are changing programatically: `this.objFormGroup.get('preferences').setValue('test', {emitEvent: false})`